# Need to display binary to Image in Django

Tags: html, django

**I need to display Binary code from my Mysql Db as image in Django.**

*views.py*

```
def editclient(request)
    clientid= request.POST['clientid']
    brachcode= request.POST['brachcode']

    if request.post and 'button2' in request.POST:
       return client_images_view(request,brachcode,clientid)
    else:
       #somecode
```

> When client_images_view is called in the above view it should display
> the image from the Mysql(which is in binary code stored as blob)

```
def client_images_view(request,brachcode,clientid):
    context = {
        'username': request.session['user_name'],
        'userrole': request.session['role'],
        'dt': request.session['dt'],
        'image':None
    }
    client_details = Client.objects.get(brachcode=brachcode, clientid=clientid)
    photo = client_details.photo
    import base64
    image = base64.b64encode(photo.getvalue())  
    image = image.decode('utf8')
    context['image'] = image
    return render(request, 'client_images.html', context)
```

**When I run this code it shows this error**

```
AttributeError at /managerial/client_edit
'bytes' object has no attribute 'getvalue'
```